# Conditional expression returning type

Tags: python, conditional-statements

I don't quite understand how this piece of code works:

```
def sequence_class(immutable):
    return tuple if immutable else list

seq = sequence_class(immutable=False)
s = seq("Nairobi")
s
['N', 'a', 'i', 'r', 'o', 'b', 'i']
seq = sequence_class(immutable=True)
s = seq("Nairobi")
s
('N', 'a', 'i', 'r', 'o', 'b', 'i')
```

It is quite obvious what it is doing, but I don't understand how the function can magically return the `tuple("Nairobi")` or `list("Nairobi")` just with the statement return `tuple if mutable else list` and without any parameter to the function.

Any clear explanation to this?

Comment: What do you mean *"without any parameter to the function"*? There **is** a parameter to the function; `immutable`!

Comment: Is it quite obvious what it's doing?

Comment: I think what you're missing here is that there are _two_ function calls, not one. The first one calls `sequence_class`; the second one calls whatever the first one returned.

Comment: @Jivan the OP is saying it's obvious. I wonder what exactly is obvious about it.

Answer (score 5):

Everything in Python is an object; the `tuple` and `list` objects are no exception.

The function simply returns a reference to either the `tuple` or the `list` object, based on the `immutable` flag:

```
>>> def sequence_class(immutable):
...     return tuple if immutable else list
... 
>>> sequence_class(True)
<class 'tuple'>
>>> sequence_class(False)
<class 'list'>
```

You then bind `seq` to that object, and calling `seq` then calls the referenced type:

```
>>> seq = sequence_class(True)
>>> seq
<class 'tuple'>
>>> seq('abc')
('a', 'b', 'c')
```

You can do the same by directly assigning `tuple` or `list` to a variable, it just creates another reference to the same object:

```
>>> foo = list
>>> foo
<class 'list'>
>>> foo('abc')
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Comment: Thanks Martjin, I got it now! "Everything in Python is an object", that's what I was missing: sequence_class(True) is a tuple and sequence_class(False) is a list. I was getting confused by the fact we are defining a function, but it returns an object.

Comment: @piquesel That's not quite right: `sequence_class(True)` is _the_ `tuple` class, not _a_ `tuple`.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `sequence_class` is exactly as if you did:

```
# if immutable == True
seq = tuple('Nairobi')

# if immutable == False
seq = list('Nairobi')
```

You just happened to replace `tuple` or `list` with the `sequence_class()` function, which returns `tuple` or `list` based on the argument you provide.

Each time you call `sequence_class()`,  this expression is replaced with the value it returns.